# Package does not exist error

Tags: java, import, package

I've just come back to fix some bugs in a small program that I've written, and now I can't compile because a package doesn't exist (according to javac).

As far as I know, I haven't changed anything in my class path, or the contents of my directories. I don't know if there have been any Java updates in between.

In my root directory, I have the four Java files that comprise my program. They don't have any package ascribed to them. Additionally, I have the directory structure `org\apache\commons\cli` in the root directory which contains the CLI java files from the Apache Commons. The Apache files do have a package ascribed that mirrors the directory structure in which they lie.

If I issue the command `javac -verbose -d build CommandLine.java`, it fails with

```
CommandLine.java:28: package org.apache.commons.cli does not exist
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;
^
```

`CommandLine.java` is the entry point of the program.

There is no attempt by the compiler to compile the CLI files, and if I compile them beforehand, the failure still takes place. Also, the CLI is also available in my classpath.

I am running javac 1.6.0_12.

What can I do/try?

.

EDITED FOR ANSWER:

As accepted below, I altered the compilation command to be:

```
javac -verbose -d build -classpath . CommandLine.java
```

Now it works. Don't know why it did before, and why it stopped now though...

.

EDITED FOR CAUSE OF PROBLEM

I installed a program that also used the CLASSPATH to run its own things. It changed the CLASSPATH that belonged to the user, but left the global one alone. I re-added the java classpath things back in and it works again!

Comment: Did you check if the CLASSPATH environment variable is actually set and points to the required libraries?

Comment: @casablanca Classpath is set and points to the correct spot.

Comment: If you mean CLASSPATH environment variable, it's wrong.  You shouldn't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you unpack that Apache JAR and add the .class files to your application?  Why didn't you just add the JAR to your `CLASSPATH`?

You should not be depending on a `CLASSPATH` environment variable.  Better to use the `-classpath` option for `javac.exe` when you compile and `java.exe` when you run.

Comment: I need this to be a stand-alone program, so I need to include the class files in the jar.

Comment: I tried a different compilation command: `javac -verbose -d build -classpath . CommandLine.java`. Now it works (for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a typo, notice you said `com\apache\commons\cli` but the import wants `org.apache.commons.cli` -- `org` vs `com`